Collect the spatial data used in an MXD file and haven't been saved in the same folder
So, I created several MXD files a long time ago, with spatial data and other reports/photos etc. inside but didn't save it all in the same folder in my computer. Now, a few days have gone by and I have no idea where to find all the data that I've used in my final layout view. So, the MXD can't be opened by anyone else in order to discuss the work.
How can I trace the data used (geodatabases, shapefiles, photos, reports) in order to send them all in the same file folder as the MXD(s)?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  All layers  have a source, and the source points to the datafile. You could use the GUI to review each source, or write a dozen lines of ArcPy to export the paths to all the sources. It would take less than a dozen more lines. to compile a hierarchy of folders and the folders and or data layers inside them, with source layers.  Then there's the "data view" in the UI, that organizes data by source folder.

If you still have access to the MXD, you can open it and check the Source of spatial layers.
Without the MXD, you are unable to unable to trace back to the data. MXD's are not spatial file containers, but source links are stored within the backend.
